# Why don't my cinoptions work?

Tags: vim, debian, indentation

I am running Vim 7.3 on Debian Wheezy i686 x86.

There is no ~/.vimrc, only /etc/vim/vimrc.

I have set cinoptions=L0:s=sl1b1

I can verify with ':verbose set cinoptions?'

that cinoptions is set to the string above from /etc/vim/vimrc.

My switch/case indent is still something like 8 shiftwidths.

What I am trying to achieve:

```
switch (foo) {
  case 0:
    bar();
  break;
```

What I get instead:

```
switch (foo) {
  case 0:
                  // blargh!
```

Why doesn't Vim respect my cinoptions?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because your `'shiftwidth'` is set to `8` (or maybe higher). Try the following to see if it addresses the behavior:

```
set shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else ever does this: quit all instances of vim before expecting to see your changes reflected. That's the only thing I can think of.

I was editing vimrc with vim, and 10-15 minutes after playing with settings, it 'just worked' automagically after I saved vimrc, quit vim, and started editing my c file (in another terminal).

I must have spent an hour changing cinoptions without any visible results (with vimrc opened).